# Resizing the terminal causes it to mix previous lines and duplicate pieces of text

Tags: terminal, zsh, gnome-terminal

When I resize my terminal, weird artifacts start to happen. The past lines start to get mixed. [Here's a gallery with what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akLi6.jpg)

What is the problem here? How do I fix it? What part of the stack is causing the problem? Is it the Terminal? The shell?

I'm using GNOME-Terminal with zsh on Ubuntu 16.10. No, manual reset doens't solve the problem.

Comment: So don't resize the terminal like that?

Comment: It's a bit of an extreme example, I admit, but overall, I do resize my terminals often in order to make them fit on the screnn... is that normal? Can it not be fixed?

Comment: Blame the terminal. Some terminals and applications solve a small part of the problem by repainting the screen using the text which was painted (and applying the new margins).  There's no general solution for this.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Could you please clarify why it is the _terminal_ to blame here (apart from your apparent generic hatred towards gnome-terminal)? Does `gnome-terminal` misinterpret any of the escape sequences it receives here? If so, we'd be happy to fix it. As I explained in my answer, there's one thing that `gnome-terminal` does differently than most others, which is extremely useful in plenty of scenarios, alas sometimes causes problems when resizing the prompt (one can easily disable this special behavior though). Also, what margings are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` (more precisely the `VTE` widget), unlike most other emulators, rewraps its contents upon resize. Generally this is a useful feature getting great feedback from users; however, with shell prompts, it indeed often causes weird behavior.

With the date being printed in the right margin, when you resize the window to become narrower, the prompt is wrapped into two lines by `gnome-terminal`. Afterwards, `zsh` is notified of the window size change and it repaints its prompt without knowing that `gnome-terminal` has wrapped it into two lines.

You can try to have a much simpler prompt (without stuff being aligned to the right), or disable rewrapping in `gnome-terminal`'s profile preferences.

Comment: I see, thanks! I disabled the date. Seems to work relatively well.

Comment: It happens in alacritty too. seems more like a zsh problem

Comment: @Jdeep it also happens with fish.